# SVN post-commit hook bat file returns Basic Auth error

Tags: svn, hook, visualsvn-server, post-commit

I am trying to get a post-commit svn hook to work. The post commit bat file has the following contents:

> "c:\program files\visualsvn server\bin\svn.exe" update "repository local address" --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username user --password pass

When i run this command from the cmd prompt it works fine and it updates to the latest revision without issues.

However, when I double click on the bat file or when visual svn server runs the hook, I get the following error:

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://xxxxx/dvn/fff'
>   OPTION of 'https://xxxxx/dvn/fff': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge

I have tried setting

```
store-passwords = yes
store-auth-creds = yes
```

but issue persists

any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this hook? Do you run it on the same server where your repository is? The error sounds like you try to create an SSL connection to something that does not use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error message with two different causes in the past:

1. An old `.svn` folder was in the repository checkout so a clean checkout fixed the problem.
2. Another time, deleting the Gnome login keyring fixed it :

   `rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring`

Otherwise, you can have a look at this [question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/19940/svn-client-authentication-error).

Hope this helps!